# addition div caused image disappear

Tags: html, css

I want to add an addition div to info-img. If I changed to `<div class="box-img"><div class="info-img"></div>......</div>`,the image is gone. What happened to this situaiton? How to I modify CSS code to show the image correctly? __

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#home-info {
height: 300px;
}
#home-info .info-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/573552/pexels-photo-573552.jpeg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100%;
}
#home-info .info-content {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="home-info">
<!-- <div class="box-img"> -->
  <div class="info-img"></div>
    <div class="info-content">
        <h2>The History of Our Hotel</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis saepe minima dolorum. Voluptatibus, recusandae. Alias nobis dolorem fugit iusto quis.</p>      
    </div>
<!-- </div> -->
</section> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem by changing the code.

```
#home-info .box-img {
height: 300px;
}
```

```css
* {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
#home-info .box-img {
height: 300px;
}
#home-info .info-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: url('https://images.pexels.com/photos/573552/pexels-photo-573552.jpeg') no-repeat center center/cover;
  height: 100%;
}
#home-info .info-content {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="home-info">
 <div class="box-img">
  <div class="info-img"></div>
    <div class="info-content">
        <h2>The History of Our Hotel</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis saepe minima dolorum. Voluptatibus, recusandae. Alias nobis dolorem fugit iusto quis.</p>      
    </div>
   </div>
</section> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed the closing in your css and the `info-img` div contains empty. You have to add any image or text to visible the div. I have updated the code. Hope this solution will be helpful.

```css
#home-info {
  height: 400px;
  width:800px;
}
#home-info .info-img img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
#home-info .box-img {
    display: flex;
}
#home-info .info-img {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
  min-height: 100%;
}
#home-info .info-content {
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
}

#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<section id="home-info">
    <div class="box-img">
        <div class="info-img">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
        </div>
        <div class="info-content">
            <h2>The History of Our Hotel</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis saepe minima dolorum. Voluptatibus, recusandae. Alias nobis dolorem fugit iusto quis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check below code snippet , As some closing bracket is missing in your css code.Hope below code will help you !

```css
#home-info {
  height: 400px;
  width:800px;
}
#home-info .box-data{
  width:100%;
  float:left;
}
#home-info .info-img {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  background: #ccc;
}
#home-info .info-img img{
  width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
#home-info .info-content {
  float:right;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 30px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
#home-info .info-content p {
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id="home-info">
  <div class="box-data">
    <div class="info-img">
      <img alt="image" height="auto" width="100%" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1531361171768-37170e369163?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1875&q=80"/>
    </div>
    <div class="info-content">
      <h2>The History of Our Hotel</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis saepe minima dolorum. Voluptatibus, recusandae. Alias nobis dolorem fugit iusto quis.</p>      
    </div>
  </div>   
</section> 
</body>
</html>
```